# How to identify the value which was assigned before the present value that is assigned?

Tags: sql, mysql, function, hive, sql-function

There are multiple historical rows present for a customer in customer table and a id has been assigned which might have changed overtime

| Name | ID | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Abhishek | 1 | 23-08-2023 |
| Abhishek | 1 | 03-08-2023 |
| Abhishek | 2 | 17-06-2023 |
| Abhishek | 3 | 09-10-2022 |
| Seema | A | 21-08-2023 |
| Seema | B | 07-06-2022 |
| Seema | C | 22-05-2020 |

Latest ids in the data

| Name | ID | Date | ** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Abhishek | 1 | 23-08-2023 |  |
| Seema | A | 21-08-2023 |  |

The required output (ID values assigned just before these latest ones) is

| Name | ID | Date | ** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Abhishek | 2 | 17-06-2023 |  |
| Seema | B | 07-06-2022 |  |

I tried lag function but in the response where there are multiple changes in the id the required output is not the second latest id but different ids involved

eg:

```
select * from (
select Name,`id,lag(id,1) over (partition by Name order by date) as
lag_id from customer_history)
```

| Name | ID | lag_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Abhishek | 1 | 2 |
| Abhishek | 2 | 3 |
| Seema | A | B |

Answer (score 1):

If this is MySQL then the dates should be formatted YYYY-mm-dd.

The following query uses GROUP BY to remove the duplicate IDs and ROW_NUMBER():

```
WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT Name, ID, MAX(Date), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY MAX(Date) DESC) AS rn
    FROM customer_history
    GROUP BY Name, ID
)
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE rn = 2;
```

Output:

| Name | ID | MAX(Date) | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Abhishek | 2 | 2023-06-17 | 2 |
| Seema | B | 2022-06-07 | 2 |

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WaWl826V)

Answer (score 0):

If your date really is formatted like that, then you need to add a `STR_TO_DATE()` function to reformat the date before you can run the previous suggested answer. Therefore:

```
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT Name, ID, MAX(STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%d-%m-%Y')), 
        ROW_NUMBER() 
         OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY MAX(STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%d-%m-%Y')) DESC) AS rn
  FROM customer_history
  GROUP BY Name, ID
)
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE rn = 2
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/VdWN5TNq